# PHP Class called function has a return

Tags: php, ajax, class, return-value

Try to explain my problem, I hope someone give me an advice 'cause I'm stuck on that for a while.

I've 2 functions in my simple class. This class send an email. First function is called `send_mail()`. Meanwhile I'm using `phpmailer class`.

```
public function send_mail() {
    $mail = new \PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->Body = $this->template();
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    if(!$mail->send())
        {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            exit;
        }

        return true;
}
```

I'm passing other extra configs. That's my code. Problem is here `$mail->Body = $this->template();`. Because `template()` function has a return.

When I make a request this class via ajax, It's not return what I want. It's return template of mail. How do I break template function return.

Here is `template` function content:

```
private function template() {
return '

        <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
          <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>'.$this->name.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="100">Surname</td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td>'.$this->surname.'</td>
          </tr>
        </table>';
}
```

This is my route for this action:

```
$app->post('/send_ticket', function () use ($app, $simpleEmail) {

    $post = $app->request()->post();
    $simpleEmail->create($post,"my@email.com");
    $simpleEmail->send_mail();

});
```

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     method: "post",
     url: url,
     data: $(".form_demo").serialize(),
     success: function (response) {

           console.log(response);

           if (response === true) {
                alert("Thank you !");
           } else  {
                alert("Oopss error. Try again !");
           }
     },
     error: function(errorCode) {
           console.log(errorCode);
     }
});
```

I hope explain.

Comment: But you need that return in order to fill $mail->Body, what is your goal?

Comment: I think you're executing `$mail->body = ...` before `$this->name` is set

Comment: Maybe you just get some error from template() and it is printed to screen, check you log file for some calls to undeclared variables.

Comment: @Vini Yes I need to this return to create mail body. But this return break my ajax request I think. I edited my code. Added ajax request

Comment: Friends, I edited my question. add more info about my send_mail function and ajax request... So send_mail function has return and I want to get this response in ajax call. But getting template function return.

Comment: Important Note : Mail successfully sent. I just want to control over response.

Comment: Did you check you log file for any errors that could be printed to output before your wanted response? Because that's probably the reason.